# Set textbox input value as a field from a database?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to get a field from my MS Access database and set it as the text box value.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix= "sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<sql:setDataSource
var = "bookdB"
scope = "session"
driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>
<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
SELECT * from Company;
</sql:query>

<!-- Create third layer -->
<form method="post" action="edit_company22.jsp">
<table style="position:absolute; left:387px; top:105px; height:124px; width:810px" border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="85%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" rules=groups>
<div style="position:absolute; left:380px; top:70px; width:850px; height:570px; border:1px solid black">
      <tr>
       <th>Phone:</th>
       <td><input type="input" name="data1" value=""></td>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
  <tr>
    <th>Phone:</th>
    <td><input type="input" name="data1" value="${row.phonenumber}" /></td>
  </tr>
 ..... //the rest of your form
</c:forEach>
```

BTW, your SQL ("SELECT * from Company;") is probably not what you really want, because you probably want only one company per form, not the whole table.

Also see the JSTL SQL tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html